# Containment between real affine varieties implies containment of complex affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was wondering whether the following is true:

Suppose we have two ideals $I,J\subset \Bbb R[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $\emptyset\neq V^\Bbb R(I)\subseteq V^\Bbb R(J)$. Is it also true that $V^\Bbb C(I)\subseteq V^\Bbb C(J)$?

I feel this should be false, but I cannot come up with any counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed false.

Let $I=(X,Y)$ and $J=(X^2+Y^2)$. The real loci are identical, consisting solely of the origin $(0,0)$, but over $\mathbb{C}$, $J$ defines the union of two lines.